# Reduce the size of website

Tags: html, magento

My website's homepage is about 8MB. Is there easy way to figure out, what all can be removed from it.

I know the slider itself has about 2.5MB of images in it. I am trying to reduce that. but still the size is too big.

the link to the website is: http://prelaunch.biocarve.com/

Please, any guidance would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Compress all images in [TinyPNG](https://tinypng.com/) to start with.

Comment: Images are compressed!

Comment: Also, run the google page insights.They will help with specific details on how to go about optimizing.I went through the console network tab for your website. A large chunk of your size seems to be due to images.The next is also js files.Try and minify them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Pagespeed Insights gives a nice overview in how to improve the speed of your website.

It also gives compressed CSS, JavaScript and images. It also gives overall solutions to make your site a little speedier.

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fprelaunch.biocarve.com%2F

You currently score a 7/100, so I would look at some of the corrections that Google provides.

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/

Answer (score 3):

1.Compress all images.

2.Remove comments from code.

3.Minify CS,Javascript and HTML files.

4.Remove Unused CSS and Javacript code.

5.Put all your javacript code in a single JS file. Do it for css also.

Answer (score 1):

I have checked your site on [this page](http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/bZ93Tz/http://prelaunch.biocarve.com/).

This page gives you insight in the size of all the components that are loaded.

As you can see, it's mainly your images:

- banner_1.jpg (619 kB)
- banner_2.jpg (468 kB)
- banner_3.jpg (614 kB)
- banner_4.jpg (447 kB)
- banner_5.jpg (588 kB)
- cosmos_bright_light_1.jpg (524 kB)
- kochia2.jpg (305 kB)
- etc

You can reduce the size of these images by resizing them with an editor like paint, photoshop, etc or an online tool like [this](http://www.imageoptimizer.net/).